# is it possible to block form submit with only nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

The HTML file where form is in doesn't have any client side javascript code. That I cannot change directly because my task is nodejs and express.

```
app.post('/',function(request,response){
const htmlCode = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/loggain.html');
const loggaInDom = new jsDOM.JSDOM(htmlCode);
const input = request.body.nickname;
try{
    if(input.length<3){
        throw new Error("nickname must be at least 3 characters");
    }
    else{
        response.cookie('nickName',input);
        response.redirect('index.html');
        console.log(request.cookies.nickName);
    }
}
catch(error){
    console.log(error);
}
});
```

This is part of my nodejs code.
I would like to block form submit when input.length is smaller than 3. Like event.preventDefault() in client javascript code. 
Now it throws error in console, which is correct, but browser keeps loading page permanently.
I cannot directly change HTML file but probably can insert client javascript file to HTML with nodejs, but I would like to know if it is possible to do with only nodeJS

Comment: The _client_ submits the form, nodejs runs on the _server_. The server has no control over what the client does.

Comment: @Andreas so the only solution is insert client javascript code with nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of throwing the error you need to send a response to the client with an error status:

```
if(input.length<3){
    response.status(400).send("nickname must be at least 3 characters");
}
```

Choose the appropriate error code depending on your error: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

You can also send json instead of text if you want some structure that your frontend can use:

```
if(input.length<3){
    response.status(400).json({
        type: "validation error",
        message: "nickname must be at least 3 characters"
    });
}
```

---

### Centralized error handling

Alternatively you may not want standardize error handling and do the `response.status()` thing at one location. Express has a way to catch errors but you cannot use the `throw` keyword. Instead you pass your error to the `next` function:

```
app.post('/',function(request, response, next){ // NOTE: next
  const htmlCode = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/loggain.html');
  const loggaInDom = new jsDOM.JSDOM(htmlCode);
  const input = request.body.nickname;
  try{
    if(input.length<3){
        throw new Error("nickname must be at least 3 characters");
    }
    else{
        response.cookie('nickName',input);
        response.redirect('index.html');
        console.log(request.cookies.nickName);
    }
  }
  catch(error){
    next(error); // This is how errors are handled in Express
  }
});
```

Now all you need to do is write a default error handler which is a special middleware that accepts four arguments instead of three or two. Make sure this middleware is loaded last after all your routes:

```
app.use((error, request, response, next) => {
    response.status(500).send(error.message);
});
```

When used with error types you can send different responses to the browser depending on types of error:

```
class ValidationError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
    this.name = "ValidationError"; // (2)
  }
}
```

Then you can throw:

```
next(new ValidationError("nickname must be at least 3 characters"))
```

Which you can handle with:

```
app.use((error, request, response, next) => {
    switch(error.name) {
        case "ValidationError":
            response.status(400);
            break;
        default:
            response.status(500);
    }
    response.send(error.message);
});
```

Comment: thanx for answer, but this shows en error page, is it possible to sit on the same page and just show the error instead of navigating to error page? or is it technically impossible?

Comment: How are you outputting the page? Do you have a templating language?

Comment: @slebetaman I am printing output with nodejs and express..I am not sure if these are relevant but I use cookie-parser, body-parser, http and fs too

Comment: @gamelover I think he is asking about the templating engine (like ejs etc.)

Comment: @AnkushVerma I don't know what is a templating engine or templating language.. I am just developing on window and visual studio code + tools which I mentioned on comment

Comment: Hmm. There's just too many things to explain in that case. The answer to "is it possible to sit on same page" is **no**. Not because of node.js but because how web browsers and the HTTP protocol works - it will always return something new. To be more accurate the answer is **yes if** - yes you can do that if you use ajax instead of a link (a tag) or a form to send your request to the server. If you use ajax then I don't have to change my answer and you just need to follow exactly what I answered above..

Comment: .. if on the other hand you use a link or a form to send request to the server then you need to modify the html page you send back - but you **will** be sending back a **new** page, it is impossible to stay on the same page without ajax. You just need to make the new page look like the old page but slightly modified..

Comment: .. if you decide to use ajax you have a choice of either using `XMLHttprequest` (or various libraries that use it) or the newer `fetch` API at the expense of not supporting older browsers (for example IE)..

Comment: .. as you can see there is a lot to explain. In fact an entire text book. At least 3 chapters of stuff to explain. I don't think I can do it in a single answer - someone else may be able to but I don't think I can. As it is my answer above assuming you already know about ajax is very long

Comment: As much as I hate w3schools (I think their information is often incorrect) they do have some good tutorial. I suggest you follow this tutorial to get ajax working then you can use my answer above: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp